# Passing information in a string from one view to another

Tags: xcode, string

I've seen this round a few posts but never really found a definitive answer. I want to pass some information stored in a string from one view to another - Lts say view1 to view2. Am I right in thinking that in the new Xcode, as long as I do not dealloc the string in view1 it will store it as it passes to view2?
Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to be following the MVC pattern; the view should not *own* the data; rather it should be given a reference to the data so it can display/otherwise manipulate it.  The data should be owned by the document/application object and given to whatever views are appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks so should I really be using NSUserdefaults?

Comment: Only if you want to persist the value between runs.  Simply store the value in your document/application class, create delegates in your views to inform the doc/app class of value changes and propagate those changes to other views if necessary.

Comment: Ok great, so would I be better using NSData? is that the best way to create delegates? Thanks

Comment: No, NSData isn't required as you are handling a single primitive type.  You need to understand the relationship between your doc/app classes and the views contained within them. This is not a question about specific Cocoa classes, but how various objects relate to each other and the responsibilities of each object.  Have to read a book on the subject?